# Quantifierisation of maps

Tags: lo.logic, fractals, definability, mapping-space

I will rewrite my question using **Matt F.** suggestion.

Consider the logical structure $L = (\mathbb{R}, +, *, 1, 0, =)$ and a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.
Consider the map $Q:2^\mathbb{R}→2^\mathbb{R}$ by
$$Q(S)=\{a:∃x,y∈S \: a \in [1, 3]∧a=f(x)∧ x = y^2\}$$
which has a definition in $L$ and uses $f$ only once. For a given logical structure with one function $f$, can we characterize the maps from $2^\mathbb{R}→2^\mathbb{R}$ which have similar first-order definitions in $L$ and use $f$ linearly (in the sence that there are no iterations $f(\dots f(\ldots))$)?

---

Motivation: I wanted to give logically correct definition of all constructions of fractals such as Apollonian gasket and Sierpinski triangle. In the setting of Apollonian gasket it is natural to replace $\mathbb{R}$ with the set $\mathcal{S}$ of circles in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $f$ with the map that inputs three pairwase tangent circles and outputs two tangent circles to a given three ones. So the map $$Q(S) = \Big\{a: \exists b, x, y, z\in S\: \{a, b\} = f(x, y, z)∧ a\notin S\Big\}$$ realize Apollonian fractal as $Q(S_0)\sqcup Q(Q(S_0))\sqcup\ldots$ where $S_0$ denote three pairwise tangent circles.

Comment: I might ask this as: Consider $\mathbb{R}$ in the language $L$ with one function $f$, and a family of relations like
$$
\big\{Sq(x,y):=x=y^2,\ \ In(x):=x\in[1,3]\big\}
$$

Consider the map $\mathcal{Q}: 2^\mathbb{R}\to 2^\mathbb{R}$ by
$$\mathcal{Q}(S) = \{a: \exists x,y\in S\ In(a) \wedge a=f(x) \wedge Sq(x,y)\}$$ which has a first-order definition in $L$ and uses $f$ only once.

For a given language with one function $f$ and a family of relations, can we characterize the maps from $2^\mathbb{R}\to 2^\mathbb{R}$ which have similar first-order definitions in $L$ and use $f$ only once?